# Access to agents that grouped using Batch block

Tags: anylogic

By `Batch` block I group together a certain amount of agents, They get a new agent identity.
I defined a temporary batch `permanent batch = false`.
How I can access to the agents that are 'inside' the new agent?

I tried to search in which population he keeps the original agents, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access through `agent.contents()`

Beware though, that you need to use unbatch if you want to use those agents for anything at all... i would say it's good practice to take these batched agents as read_only otherwise unpredictable things might happen

Comment: You mean that after the group (new agent) is out of the Batch block I can't access to the parameter `agent.contents().get(0).myIntVariable = 123`?

Comment: you have to do ((AgentType)agent.contents().get(0)).myIntVariable=123 i think... but i would say to only change the values of the agents when they are unbatched as best practice

Comment: Ok, but why? The original agents are not independent?

Comment: do it if you want... i just have seen situations in which unpredictable things happen... You can think about it like this: the internal logic might have bugs, so to be on the safe side, i will do everything when things are unbatched.... Nevertheless, do it if you want, it should be valid to do it... i'm just giving you a suggestion based on my experience... sometimes it does what you want, sometimes it doesnt